# Why is the follow HLC query returning undefined?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I want to retrieve a participant by it's Id and log the details to the console. I have used named composer query to retrieve the participant. The access control is generated automatically (default).

The model file is:

```
namespace org.example.empty

participant SampleParticipant identified by partId {
  o String partId
  o String LName
  o String FName  
}
transaction getSampleParticipant {
  o String partyId
}
```

query.qry file:

```
query selectParticipantById {
  description: "Select participant by Id"
  statement: 
    SELECT org.example.empty.SampleParticipant  
    WHERE (partId == _$pId)
}
```

The Transaction processor is:

```
/**
 * get a participant.
 * @param {org.example.empty.getSampleParticipant} txgetParty 
 * @transaction
 */

async function getParty (txgetParty) {
  const queryResult = await query ('selectParticipantById', {pId: txgetParty.partyId})  
  console.log('Participant detail.')
  console.log(queryResult.partId)
  console.log(queryResult.FName)
  console.log(queryResult.LName)
}
```

After installing this in the Composer playground, I create a SampleParticipant and submit the getSampleParticipant transaction. The console output says 'undefined' three times. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the query returns an array of objects. So, using `for` loop to access the array elements will solve the problem.

```
    for (let index= 0; index< queryResult.length; n++) {

         console.log("partId: " + queryResult[index].partId );
         console.log("First Name: " + queryResult[index].FName);
         console.log("Last Name: " + queryResult[index].LName);
      }
```